# After cropping an image in Typo3 9.5 aspect ratio jumps back on first value

Tags: image, image-processing, typo3, crop, typo3-9.x

Using typo3 9.5.9, if have defined two crop-formats for images in "mysitepackage/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_reference.php":

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['columns']['crop']['config'] = array(
    'type' => 'imageManipulation',
    'ratios' => array(
        '1.0' => 'A',
        '2.0' => 'B',
    ),
);
```

In BE (eg. when working on a fal-image in ce "text and image") I can correctly choose between the two formats A and B.

Cropping format A works fine: I can select part of the image, save and it will be correctly displayed in FE.

Cropping format B fails. As soon as the content-element gets saved, image format A is applied on top of the selected area of format B.

The role of A and B change if their order is changed in sys_file_reference.php.

With more than two aspect ratios, image manipulation always jumps back to the first given aspect ratio.

Any hint what could be wrong?

Comment: Is it `ratios` or should it be  `allowedAspectRatios` ?

Comment: yes `ratios` does not exist. it's `config` -> `cropVariants` -> `yourvariantkey` -> `allowedAspectRatios` -> ...
Refer to the docs for more information on this: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/ImageManipulation.html

Comment: Yes, thank you, that made the difference. Now it works.

Comment: Just for the record:

`sys_file_reference -> columns -> crop -> config -> ratios` seems to work, but doesn't

`sys_file_reference -> columns -> crop -> config -> cropVariants -> default -> allowedAspectRatios -> ...` works fine